# jQuery tree view plugin for selecting multiple categories (checkboxes)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that'll be used for selecting categories assigned to a product.  I've checked out the jsTree plugin, but it's overkill.  Would anyone recommend a simple, lightweight tree plugin or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: I made one of those not to long ago... Dunno where I put it though, I'll howl if I find it xD

Comment: you might find it overkill, but it's a mature stable library. Out there is full of untested libraries that could fail anytime